# dynamically added link buttons are not triggering the events

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

In my project I am dynamically adding a group of link buttons. When I created events for those link buttons those are not triggering. here is my code.

```
    namespace listofdirectories
    {
        public partial class directories : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string[] drives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives();

                foreach (string str in drives)
                {
                    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                    lnk.Text = str;
                    lnk.ID = str;
                    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(lnk);
                    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                    lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_Click);
                }
            }
        protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("files.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is someone still uses asp webpages? Why?

Answer (score 1):

It is the special characters in your ID that is causing the issue. You are assigning the ID as "**C:\**" or "**D:\**".

I have added a counter based ID to get it working

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string str in drives)
{
    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
    lnk.Text = str;
    lnk.ID = i.ToString();         

    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(lnk);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_Click);
    i++;

}
```

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore
>   character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces
>   or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

For reference read this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @prashanti if it solves your problem, request you to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your click event must be assigned earlier then add control in panel.

```
foreach (string str in drives)
            {
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = str;
                lnk.ID = str;
                lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_Click);
                this.Panel1.Controls.Add(lnk);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            }
```